# Java - Store a CSV in 2D array

Tags: arrays, csv, 2d

Can I in some way store a csv file in a multi-dimensional array?
For example:

I store in

```
[0][x] - a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

and

```
[1][X] - a,h,d,r,f,c,o
```

each letter is stored in the`[x]` part(column) and the `[0]` and the `[1]` (rows) are new lines

=> So that if I call `[0][5]` - I get `e`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, ofcourse you can!

Long answer: Yes, this is totaly possible since CSV format was designed to store tabular data.
If you want to learn more about the format itself take a look at [this video](http://youtube.com/watchhttp://youtube.com/watch?v=1L6kTOG3y1Y).